# Creating a percentage type in C#

Tags: c#

My application deals with percentages a lot. These are generally stored in the database in their written form rather than decimal form (50% would be stored as 50 rather than 0.5). There is also the requirement that percentages are formatted consistently throughout the application.

To this end i have been considering creating a struct called percentage that encapsulates this behaviour. I guess its signature would look something like this:

```
public struct Percentage
{
    public static Percentage FromWrittenValue();
    public static Percentage FromDecimalValue();

    public decimal WrittenValue { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a reasonable thing to do? It would certianly encapsulate some logic that is repeated many times but it is straightforward logic that peopel are likely to understand. I guess i need to make this type behave like a normal number as much as possible however i am wary of creating implicit conversions to a from decimal in case these confuse people further.

Any suggestions of how to implement this class? or compelling reasons not to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Percentage` class should not be concerned with formatting itself for the UI. Rather, implement [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) and [ICustomFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) to handle formatting logic.

As for conversion, I'd go with standard [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) route, which would allow .NET to handle this class correctly, plus a separate `PercentageParser` utility class, which would delegate calls to `TypeDescriptor` to be more usable in external code. In addition, you can provide `implicit` or `explicit` conversion operator, if this is required.

And when it comes to `Percentage`, I don't see any compelling reason to wrap simple `decimal` into a separate `struct` other than for semantic expressiveness.

Comment: I appreciate that the logic should be provided by other classes. But to my mind there is still a lot of value in having a percentage class that uses a default ToString method that gives a nice looking percentage string. Especially as this needs to be displayed in multiple presentation layers. (A mixture of Asp.Net, Winforms, and pdf reports).

Comment: ToString(), as it is done in other .NET classes, can delegate all the work to the IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter. See DateTime.ToString for an example.

Comment: Of course, people who always write perfect code never have to worry about such tosh as semantic expressiveness. They will never again look at their perfect code wondering just what the hell is going on. -- If you'd like a more specific reason, a type for Percentage could be extremely useful, as long as you made it a class which encapsulates a decimal number between 0 and 1 inclusive. This applies very well to probability applications. I'd use this type any time I have to model a number in a bounded range, such as the output of a slider control in the UI or weightings in a neural net.

Answer (score 15):

I am actually a little bit flabbergasted at the cavalier attitude toward data quality here.
Unfortunately, the colloquial term "percentage" can mean one of two different things: a probability and a variance. The OP doesn't specify which, but since variance is usually calculated, I'm guessing he may mean percentage as a probability or fraction (such as a discount).

The **extremely good reason** for writing a `Percentage` class for this purpose has nothing to do with presentation, but with making sure that you prevent those silly silly users from doing things like entering invalid values like -5 and 250.

I'm thinking really more about a `Probability` class: a numeric type whose valid range is strictly [0,1]. You can encapsulate that rule in ONE place, rather than writing code like this in 37 places:

```
 public double VeryImportantLibraryMethodNumber37(double consumerProvidedGarbage)
 {
    if (consumerProvidedGarbage < 0 || consumerProvidedGarbage > 1)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Here we go again.");

    return someOtherNumber * consumerProvidedGarbage;
 }
```

instead you have this nice implementation. No, it's not fantastically obvious improvement, but remember, you're doing that value-checking in each time you're using this value.

```
 public double VeryImportantLibraryMethodNumber37(Percentage guaranteedCleanData)
 {
    return someOtherNumber * guaranteedCleanData.Value;
 }
```

Comment: What if -5% and 250% are valid percentages.  Which they are in some cases.

Comment: @MisterBee in cases where those values are valid, this class wouldn't apply. No class should fit every situation, in fact if you're properly designing using SOLID, a class should fit one-and-only-one situation. In probability/likelihood situations they very much aren't valid. Zero is the lowest possible value (you can't get less likely than impossible) and One the highest (you can't get more likely than certainty).

Answer (score 5):

It seems like a reasonable thing to do, but I'd reconsider your interface to make it more like other CLR primitive types, e.g. something like.

```
// all error checking omitted here; you would want range checks etc.
public struct Percentage
{
    public Percentage(decimal value) : this()
    {
        this.Value = value
    }

    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public static explicit operator Percentage(decimal d)
    {
        return new Percentage(d);
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(Percentage p)
    {
        return this.Value;
    }

    public static Percentage Parse(string value)
    {
        return new Percentage(decimal.Parse(value));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}%", this.Value);
    }
}
```

You'd definitely also want to implement `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>` as well as all the corresponding operators and overrides of `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, etc. You'd also probably also want to consider implementing the `IConvertible` and `IFormattable` interfaces.

This is a lot of work. The struct is likely to be somewhere in the region of 1000 lines and take a couple of days to do (I know this because it's a similar task to a `Money` struct I wrote a few months back). If this is of cost-benefit to you, then go for it.

Comment: If he's insistent on taking this approach, it's also worth overloading all the arithmetic and comparison operators.

Comment: @Noldorin - Um, I said "as well as all the corresponding operators and overrides of Equals, GetHashCode, etc" in the context of those interfaces...?

Answer (score 3):

This question reminds me of the Money class [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) talks about- the link might give you food for thought.

Answer (score 3):

Even in 2022, .Net 6 I found myself using something just like this. I concur with Michael on his answer for the OP and like to extend it for future Googlers.

Creating a value type would be indispensable in explaining the domain's intent with enforced immutability. Notice especially in the Fraction Record you will get a Quotient that would normally cause an exception however here we can safely show d / 0 with no error, likewise all other inherited children are also granted that protection (It also offers an excellent place to establish simple routines to check validity, data rehydration (as if DBA's don't make mistakes), serialization concerns just to name a few.)

```
namespace StackOverflowing;

// Honor the simple fraction
public record class Fraction(decimal Dividend, decimal Divisor) 
{
    public decimal Quotient => (Divisor > 0.0M) ? Dividend / Divisor : 0.0M;

    // Display dividend / divisor as the string, not the quotient
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return $"{Dividend} / {Divisor}";
    }
};

// Honor the decimal based interpretation of the simple fraction
public record class DecimalFraction(decimal Dividend, decimal Divisor) : Fraction(Dividend, Divisor)
{
    // Change the display of this type to the decimal form
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Quotient.ToString();
    }
};

// Honor the decimal fraction as the basis value but offer a converted value as a percentage
public record class Percent(decimal Value) : DecimalFraction(Value, 100.00M)
{
    // Display the quotient as it represents the simple fraction in a base 10 format aka radix 10
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Quotient.ToString("p");
    }
};

// Example of a domain value object consumed by an entity or aggregate in finance
public record class PercentagePoint(Percent Left, Percent Right) 
{ 
    public Percent Points => new(Left.Value - Right.Value);

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Points.Dividend} points";
    }
}



[TestMethod]
public void PercentScratchPad()
{
    var approximatedPiFraction = new Fraction(22, 7);
    var approximatedPiDecimal = new DecimalFraction(22, 7);
    var percent2 = new Percent(2);
    var percent212 = new Percent(212);
    var points = new PercentagePoint(new Percent(50), new Percent(40));

    TestContext.WriteLine($"Approximated Pi Fraction: {approximatedPiFraction}");
    TestContext.WriteLine($"Approximated Pi Decimal: {approximatedPiDecimal}");
    TestContext.WriteLine($"2 Percent: {percent2}");
    TestContext.WriteLine($"212 Percent: {percent212}");
    TestContext.WriteLine($"Percentage Points: {points}");
    TestContext.WriteLine($"Percentage Points as percentage: {points.Points}");
}
```

﻿ PercentScratchPad
Standard Output: 
TestContext Messages:

```
Approximated Pi Fraction: 22 / 7
Approximated Pi Decimal: 3.1428571428571428571428571429
2 Percent: 2.00%
212 Percent: 212.00%
Percentage Points: 10 points
Percentage Points as percentage: 10.00%
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you just stick with using the `double` type here (I don't see any use for the `decimal` type either, as wouldn't actually seem to require base-10 precision in the low decimal places). By creating a `Percentage` type here, you're really performing unnecessary encapsulation and just making it harder to work with the values in code. If you use a `double`, which is customary for storying percentages (among many other tasks), you'll find dealing with the BCL and other code a lot nicer in most cases.

The only extra functionality that I can see you need for percentages is the ability to convert to/from a percentage string easily. This can be done very simply anyway using single lines of code, or even extension methods if you want to abstract it slightly.

*Converting to percentage string :*

```
public static string ToPercentageString(this double value)
{
    return value.ToString("#0.0%"); // e.g. 76.2%
}
```

*Converting from percentage string :*

```
public static double FromPercentageString(this string value)
{
    return double.Parse(value.SubString(0, value.Length - 1)) / 100;
}
```

Comment: If it is the case of needing to convert from strings easily then writing extension methods could be useful.

Comment: @RichardOD: You read my mind. I had just been editing the post to give examples of extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be mixing up presentation and logic here. I would convert the percentage to a decimal or float fraction (0.5) when getting it from the database and then let the presentation deal with the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not create a separate class for that - this just creates more overhead. I thinkg it will be faster just to use `double` variables set to the database value.

If it is common knowledge that the database stores percentages as 50 instead of 0.5, everybody will understand statemens like `part = (percentage / 100.0) * (double)value`.